# Why I am getting this kind of error in python -- Unresolved reference

Tags: python, class, object, module

I have two files

A module Student with the content:

```
Class Student :
       def_init_(self, name, work, GPA, attendance):
               self. name = name
               self. work = work
               self.gpa = gpa
               self. attendance = attendance
```

and a main file

```
from Student import Student 
Student1= Student("Johan","teaching",5.4,False)
Print(Student1.name)


#In <module> Student1=Student("Johan","Teacher",5.4,False)
#TypeError: Student() takes no argument .
```

Please help me to solve this error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it is a formatting issue, but you have an error in your initializer. Instead of `def __init__` you only have `def_init_`.

Comment: If that was the cause of your problem, accepting the answer and/or upvote would be great!